# Symfony form entity from joined entities

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I want to create a form select field which looks like this:

```
<select>
<option value="product.product_id">product_details.detail_name</option>
etc...
</select>
```

The value is not the problem, the problem is with the label.

I have a product entity and a productDetails entity which contains translated data about a product.

So, in my form type class, in the buildForm method, I have this:

```
    $builder->add('product', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Product',
        'property' => 'details.detail_name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p, pd')
                ->join('p.details', 'pd')
                ->where('pd.language_id = :lang')
                ->setParameter('lang', 'en');
        }));
```

I want the property to be the details.detail_name.

I tried different values for this property value. Like 'details.detail_name', 'pd.detail_name' and 'p.details.detail_name'.

But it seems to be impossible to get the property to display the detail name.

When I use to above mentioned code, I get this error:

```
Neither property "detail_name" nor method "getDetailName()" nor method "isDetailName()" exists in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"
```

This getDetailName() method does exist in the ProductDetails entity, and I have checked the entities and they all seem to be okay. Also, they work just fine when I use these entities outside the form.

I also tried to execute the resulting query directly on my database, and it gives me the expected results. The detail_name are in the right language.

So, can somebody help me on how to make the select choice list I want, with a joined query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working. Below, I'm showing how I'm doing this, in case someone else has the same problem.

I am now using a custom form type.

And in the setDefaultOptions, I am calling a repository method, which returns an array with "product_id" => "detail_name".

```
class ProductChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'choices' => $this->repository->findAllProductsForForm('nl', true)
            ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product_choice';
    }
}
```

In the $this->repository->findAllProductsForForm method, I am using a query and a foreach loop to make the array suitable for the choice list.

Then, I had to register the repository and this type in my services.xml file:

```
<service id="mybundle.repository.product"
         factory-service="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
         factory-method="getRepository"
         class="MyBundle\Repository\ProductRepository" >
    <argument>MyBundle:Product</argument> <!-- not sure why I need this, but it wouldn't work without it -->
</service>

<service id="mybundle.xxx.form.product_choice_type" class="Mybundle\Form\Type\ProductChoiceType">
    <argument type="service" id="mybundle.repository.product" />
    <tag name="form.type" alias="product_choice" />
</service>
```

And then, in the root form type (I think it's called that) I use the 'product_choice' as a form type.

I'm not sure if this the best way to do this, but at least it works.

Now I only need to figure out how to pass on the current language of the user on to the repository, but that's a problem for later.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see your Method `Product::getDetails` returns `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` not `ProductDetails' entity (so collection not single object). It mean that product is related with details using one-to-many/many-to-many association.

You can try to do it from product details side then:

```
$builder->add(
    'product',
    'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:ProductDetails',
        'property' => 'detail_name',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('pd')
                ->select('pd, p')
                ->join('pd.product', 'p')
                ->where('pd.language_id = :lang')
                ->setParameter('lang', 'en');
         }
    )

);
```

Comment: I tried this piece of code, and it worked. But, the value of the select is now the id of the product detail. It should be the product_id.